# Keep multiple rows during PIVOT in Snowflake

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to transpose rows into columns in Snowflake.

Suppose I have the following table BASE

| ID | value | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 'A' |
| 1 | 200 | 'B' |
| 1 | 300 | 'B' |
| 2 | 400 | 'A' |

The output should be as follows:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 |
| 1 | 100 | 300 |
| 2 | 400 | NULL |

Currently I am pivoting the table with

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN TYPE = 'A' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL AS A,
CASE WHEN TYPE = 'B' THEN VALUE ELSE NULL AS B
FROM BASE
```

For now the GROUP BY statement is missing. Typically I would GROUP BY ID, but that does not account for keeping one row per each value on the same TYPE and ID.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Cheers,
P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  You can use `row_number()` to get multiple rows:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'A' THEN VALUE END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'B' THEN VALUE END) AS B
FROM (SELECT B.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, TYPE ORDER BY VALUE) as seqnum
      FROM BASE B
     ) B
GROUP BY ID, seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work, too:

```
select *
from base_table
     pivot(sum(value) for type in ('A','B')) as p
order by id;
```